# SQL: How to sum up count for many decades?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am learning SQL queries and have a question as below

"A decade is a sequence of ten consecutive years, e.g. 1982, 1983... 1991. For each decade, compute the total number of publications in DBLP in that decade."

I have come up with a temporary table for the count of each year with `select count(id) as cnt, year from publication group by year`

So the next step is to sum up the cnt for year decade. After some research, I found that I could use the ***BETWEEN*** operator. However, I still need to specify the range one by one. Is there any better way to do this? (The year range is 1900 - 2015)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I would just divide the year by ten, then take the floor (which is probably done implicitly, but I'm not super familiar with MySQL).

```
SELECT (FLOOR(Year / 10) * 10) AS Decade, COUNT(id) AS Cnt
FROM Publication
GROUP BY FLOOR(Year/ 10)
```

The trick with this approach is that I'm assuming you want `1900-1909`, `1910-1919`, `1920-1919`, `...`, `2010-2015`.  If your "ten consecutive years" rule doesn't fall like that, you'll have to add in some arithmetic. But it sounds like it should, and even if it doesn't this is probably more ideal for users.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I find the GROUP BY and LEFT() can help a lot.

```
select LEFT(year, 3) as decade , sum(cnt) from 
(select count(id) as cnt, year from publication group by year) 
as T1
group by LEFT(year, 3)
;
```

The result is

decade cnt

```
NULL    6
193 55
194 139
195 1066
196 8066
197 28449
198 93203
199 359628
200 1249767
201 947365
```

Do please give your suggestions if there are better ways to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new with SQL so this is my most simple answer.
Maybe it will help you

```
SELECT(MAX(year_2)-MIN(year_1))/10.0
FROM data-X;
```